# OpenSearch: Hide document from user if user has tags

Tags: amazon-opensearch

We have an opensearch index with documents that look like:

```
{
  internal_id: 123,
  codename: 'Zazoo'
}
```

We also have users, and each user has a list of ids they are not allowed to retrieve from the opensearch database.

Suppose a user is not supposed to be able to retrieve documents with `internal_id` 123, for example. How can we craft a `tags` query in opensearch that prevents the user from accessing the document with `internal_id` 123?

Comment: I thought the elastic tag might draw insights from folks using the elastic side of the codebase. Is there no tags-based shared solution used by Elastic and Opensearch?

Answer (score 0):

We removed the document from the target users with the following query:

```
      bool: {
        must_not: {
          terms: {
            internal_id: 123,
          }
        }
      }
```